# Should I leave the root account in the user table of mysql DB?

Tags: mysql

If I have ensured that connections to the MySQL db are not using the root user account. I have created application specific users with appropriate schema privileges. I am just a little leery that I may be overlooking some system level function that uses the root user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should leave a root account - actually I am not sure you can remove it completely anyhow without some consequences. I am not sure, but I think it is needed for the password recovery, if all admin passwords are lost - you can start MySQL deamon (or service) with password free mode using special syntax. So basically, whoever has sudo access to your server can always access/alter all MySQL data.

But you should DEFINITELY define a password for the root and store it safe - not on the server, not even obscure, and possibly limit it to be able to connect only from localhost.

By default, this is the case, root user cannot connect from any host but localhost, so don't change that.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the name of the default MySQL root user. I usually do that on all my MySQL installations.